# Sorting Columns within csv files(Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, sorting, csv

Having issues with code. was given a file called "racing.csv" that stored the variables found in the "Drive" class. Concept behind the problem is that the program should sort the racetimes (lowest to highest) and assign points to the top 3 racers then export this data to a new file. All code is working fine aside from when I'm calling the shortBubbleSort on Drive and isn't sorting the racetimes correctly. Help is appreciated.

```
import csv
class Drive(object):
    driver = ""
    team = ""
    racetime = 0.0
    points = 0

    def __init__(self,driver,team,racetime,points):
        self.driver = driver 
        self.team = team
        self.racetime = racetime 
        self.points = points

f = open('racing.csv', 'r')
csv_f = list(csv.reader(f))

driverclasses = [] 
for i in range(len(csv_f)): 
    d = Drive(csv_f[i][0],csv_f[i][1],csv_f[i][2],csv_f[i][3]) 
    driverclasses.append(d)

for row in csv_f:
    print (row)

for x in range(0, 6):
    csv_f[x][2]=(input("Enter Racetime"))

def shortBubbleSort(alist):
    exchanges = True
    passnum = len(alist)-1
    while passnum > 0 and exchanges:
       exchanges = False
       for i in range(passnum):
           if alist[i]>alist[i+1]:
               exchanges = True
               temp = alist[i]
               alist[i] = alist[i+1]
               alist[i+1] = temp
       passnum = passnum-1

shortBubbleSort(Drive)
print(csv_f)

csv_f[0][3] = 25
csv_f[1][3] = 18
csv_f[2][3] = 15


f = open('RacingResults.csv', 'w')
for row in csv_f:
        print (row)
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

**range function sintax*: `range([start], stop[, step])`

start: Starting number of the sequence.

stop: Generate numbers up to, but not including this number.

step: Difference between each number in the sequence.

```
def shortBubbleSort(alist):
    for passnum in range(len(alist)-1,0,-1):
        for i in range(passnum):
            if alist[i]>alist[i+1]:
                temp = alist[i]
                alist[i] = alist[i+1]
                alist[i+1] = temp
```

Comment: probably no, since there is a lot of other problems: shortBubbleSort(Drive)

Comment: I've tried a simple example and the solution I posted seems to work. Let's see what @Sandy says :)